# How to zoom in into a SwiftUI Text Editor

Tags: swift, swiftui, zooming, text-editor

I am building a SwiftUI text editor in which I need the user to be able to zoom in. However, I don't know how to zoom in to the SwiftUI text editor naturally -- I want to make the zooming function of the text editor smooth. In the code below, what I've tried is changing the font size. I've also tried the "scaleEffect" method, but it pixelates the text editor text

Here is a gif of what I essentially want to achieve:
[image]

Here is the gif of my current text editor:
[image]

Here is my current code:

```
ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(0 ..< wordPad.pages.count) { page in
                    TextEditor(text: $wordPad.pages[page])
                        .frame(width: 800 * scale, height: 800 * scale * sqrt(2))
                        .font(Font.custom(fontName, size: fontSize * scale))
                        .lineSpacing(10 * scale)
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5))
                                .padding(40 * scale)
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                }
            }
            
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        }
        .gesture(MagnificationGesture()
                    .onChanged { scale = $0 }
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the type size always leads to different line breaks, because Apple is changing the character spacing based on the display size.

The only workaround I found is to still use `.scaleEffect` but start with an "enlarged" version of all values (x4) and an initial scale of 0.25 – so it mainly scales down and doesn't pixelate as quickly:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var wordPad = ""
    @State private var scaleGesture: CGFloat = 1
    @State private var scale: CGFloat = 0.25
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                TextEditor(text: $wordPad)
                    .frame(width:1200, height: 1200)
                    .font(.system(size: 48))
                    .lineSpacing(40)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    .allowsTightening(false)
                
            }
            .scaleEffect(scaleGesture * scale)
            
            .gesture(
                MagnificationGesture()
                    .onChanged {
                        scaleGesture = $0
                        print($0)
                    }
                    .onEnded { value in
                        print ( scale, value)
                        scale = scale * scaleGesture
                        scaleGesture = 1
                    }
            )
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(.gray)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is problematic because it causes the text to be extremely pixelated when you zoom in. It has the same issue as the scaleEffect() modifier. Is there some other way where I can achieve the same animation as the code mentioned above (or scaleEffect()) without reducing the quality of the text?

Comment: you are absolutely right, sorry for that. I updated my answer.

Comment: This still didn't fix the issue. I've resorted to using a UIViewRepresentable with UITextView (UIKit). How do I achieve the zoom in capability of google docs or even Essayist????